# Iterate vector with 'grouped' elements?

Tags: c++, range, iteration, c++17

Consider the example of 4 colors packed in the same vector (this aspect of the design cannot be changed easily - eg. from a third party):

```
std::vector rgb_colors = {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4};
```

The following can work:

```
for (size_t ci = 0; ci + 2 < rgb_colors.size(); ci+=3) {
  auto& red_component = rgb_colors[ci];
  auto& green_component = rgb_colors[ci+1];
  auto& blue_component = rgb_colors[ci+2];
  //...
}
```

In a vacuum this method is 'innocent' enough.
However, with modern c++/etc., I usually steer away from this method of coding, since it's more brittle/error-prone/redundant/etc. and now prefers range based for loops, iterators, etc. .

So what is a more **expressive** or *elegant* way to solve this ?

**Update:**
Added a note about that the 'data layout' cannot be easily changed.

Comment: `struct color { int red; int green; int blue; }; std::vector<color> rgb_colors = {{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3},{4,4,4}};`

Comment: Could you describe, what you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to create an iterator adapter to retrieve the `n`, `n+1`, and `n+2`th elements of the vector, but you're probably better off doing what @NathanOliver said

Comment: this could maybe make a good quesiton for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (supposed you turn it into complete and correct code), but here it is imho purely opinion based

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, create a `struct` representing a color or rather use one that probably comes with whatever library you are using for graphics, so that you can interact with it properly:

```
struct color {
    int red, green, blue;
    // Add members as you see fit
};

std::vector rgb_colors = {color{1,1,1}, color{2,2,2}, color{3,3,3}, color{4,4,4}};
// or
// std::vector<color> rgb_colors = {{1,1,1}, {2,2,2}, {3,3,3}, {4,4,4}};

for (auto& c : rgb_colors) {
  auto& red_component = c.red;
  auto& green_component = c.green;
  auto& blue_component = c.blue;
  //...
}
```

---

Or, focusing less on the concrete example, you can use a range/iterator adaptor like `boost::adaptors::stride`:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/strided.hpp>

//...

for (auto& c : boost::adaptors::stride(rgb_colors, 3)) {
  auto& red_component = (&c)[0];
  auto& green_component = (&c)[1];
  auto& blue_component = (&c)[2];
  //...
}
```

This still (as in your example) requires you to make sure that the length of the vector is divisible by `3` to avoid UB and that the elements are part of a continuous array (as `std::vector` provides) in the first place, so that the pointer arithmetic `(&c)[i]` has well-defined behavior.

Comment: The answer is correct, but doing all this stuff in plain C++ is useless. If Windows, structs that define colors and alpha are already there and established. If using libraries such as OpenCV, structs are there. 

Doing it at the C++ level only is ueless C++ doesn't itself have GUI libraries, hence the lack of any such defined structure.

Comment: is this C++20 or already fine with C++17? (I mean the `std::vector rbg_colors = ...`)

Comment: @idclev463035818 CTAD was introduced in C++17

Comment: @NathanOliver omg I am soo much behind. For daily work I am bound to C++11 still :/

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Yes sure, the type given by the library should be used instead, so that it can interact with it properly. I have added a comment to the answer.

Comment: I'd prefer ```std::vector<color> rgb_colors = {{1,1,1}, {2,2,2}, {3,3,3}, {4,4,4}};``` -- 13 characters less in this case

Comment: I'd also note the `(&c)[1]` part assumes contiguous storage, which is fine for `std::vector` but not with many other ranges.

Comment: @aschepler Added.

Comment: @SPD I have added that variation.

Comment: `boost::adaptors::stride` is something in the ballpark of what I needed/was looking for, however the example you give looks like it could go out of bounds if the size isn't divisible by 3 ?

Comment: @darune Yes, as I mentioned it will have undefined behavior if the size is not divisible by `3`. What do you want it to do if the size isn't divisible by `3`?

Answer (score 2):

As already noted in comments, the input data could be better defined to match its meaning, and that would avoid the issue best.

But if you're for some reason stuck with a sequence where N elements at a time mean something, and you'll need to work with it a lot, here's how I'd use `boost::iterator_adaptor` to create an iterator which grabs N elements at a time.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp>

namespace N_elements_iterator_detail {
    template <typename T, std::size_t N>
    using ignore_N = T;

    template <typename T, typename IndSeq>
    struct repeat_type_helper;
    template <typename T, std::size_t ...Inds>
    struct repeat_type_helper<T, std::index_sequence<Inds...>>
    { using type = std::tuple<ignore_N<T, Inds>...>; };

    template <typename T, std::size_t N>
    using repeat_type = typename repeat_type_helper<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>::type;

    template <typename IndSeq>
    struct deref_helper;

    template <std::size_t ...Inds>
    struct deref_helper<std::index_sequence<Inds...>>
    {
        template <typename RetType, typename FwdIter>
        static RetType deref(FwdIter iter) {
            FwdIter iter_array[] =
                { (static_cast<void>(Inds), iter++) ... };
            return RetType( *iter_array[Inds]... );
        }
    };
}

template <typename FwdIter,
          typename std::iterator_traits<FwdIter>::difference_type N,
          std::enable_if_t<(N>0)>* = nullptr>
class N_elements_iterator :
    public boost::iterator_adaptor<
        N_elements_iterator<FwdIter, N>, // CRTP Derived type
        FwdIter,                         // Implementation base iterator
        N_elements_iterator_detail::repeat_type<
            typename std::iterator_traits<FwdIter>::value_type, N>,
        boost::use_default,              // Iterator category
        N_elements_iterator_detail::repeat_type<
            typename std::iterator_traits<FwdIter>::reference, N>>
{
public:
    using N_elements_iterator::iterator_adaptor::iterator_adaptor;

private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    typename N_elements_iterator::reference dereference() const {
        return N_elements_iterator_detail::deref_helper<
            std::make_index_sequence<N>>
            ::template deref<typename N_elements_iterator::reference>(
                this->base());
    }

    void advance(typename N_elements_iterator::difference_type dist) {
        std::advance(this->base_reference(), N * dist);
    }

    void increment() { advance(1); }
    void decrement() { advance(-1); }

    // N must be the same, but we can subtract for example
    // N_elements_iterator<C::iterator, N> and N_elements_iterator<C::const_iterator, N>
    template <typename OtherIter>
    auto distance_to(const N_elements_iterator<OtherIter, N>& other) const {
        return N * std::distance(this->base(), other.base());
    }
};

template <auto N, typename FwdIter>
N_elements_iterator<FwdIter, N> make_N_elements_iterator(FwdIter iter)
{ return N_elements_iterator<FwdIter, N>{ iter }; }

// -----

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector rgb_colors = {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4};

    for (auto c = make_N_elements_iterator<3>(rgb_colors.cbegin());
         c != make_N_elements_iterator<3>(rgb_colors.cend());
         ++c) {
        auto&& [red, green, blue] = *c;
        std::cout << "red " << red
                  << ", green " << green
                  << ", blue " << blue
                  << '\n';
    }
}
```

See [this program on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32231adaa13cbf30).